# Adding n and categorization next to horizontal boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add n= x and categories next to each horizontal boxplot and having issues with `stat_n_text()` function. This way both the x=n and categories aligns with the boxplot. Is there an alterative to this? I have included some code to play around with and a picture of what I am trying to achieve. Many thanks and appreciate any help.

```
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)
library(EnvStats)


p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = -0.5))

p1 <- p + geom_density(aes(x = carat), inherit.aes = FALSE) 
p2 <- p + geom_boxploth(aes(fill = cut)) +stat_n_text() + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color = 'white'),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
p1/p2 + plot_layout(ncol = 1, nrow = 2, heights = c(2, 1),
                    guides = 'collect')
```

Edit: Is it possible to have the axis below while deleting the legends? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Edit: Is it possible to have the axis below while deleting the legends?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `stat_n_text()` is what you're looking for.
A simpler approach:

```
ltext <- diamonds %>% 
               group_by(cut) %>% 
               summarise(n=n()) %>% 
               apply(.,1,function(x) paste0(x[1]," (n=",x[2],")"))
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=0.5)) +
            geom_boxplot(aes(fill=cut)) +
            scale_fill_discrete(labels=ltext)
```

[image: boxplot output with custom labels]

Answer (score 0):

A combined approach to get your desired figure would be something like this:

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)
library(EnvStats)

p <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  mutate(cut = paste0(cut, ', n = ', n())) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = -0.5))

p1 <- p + geom_density(aes(x = carat), inherit.aes = FALSE) 
p2 <- p + geom_boxploth(aes(fill = cut)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(byrow = TRUE)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color = 'white'),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.key.height = unit(8, "mm"),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "mm")) 
p1/p2 + plot_layout(ncol = 1, nrow = 2, heights = c(2, 1))
```

[image]